# How to upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 from 18.04 via live USB or ISO file

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, system-installation, upgrade, iso

I'm on 18.04 now and I've already downloaded the ISO file for 20.04 and I wish not to download again through system updater because of my limited Internet connection. How can I upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 via the ISO file? I've tried creating live USB and booting from it and there was no option to upgrade only Erase and install. How can I upgrade through my ISO file?

Comment: Make sure you're booting the installer in the same mode (UEFI or Legacy/"BIOS") the system was originally installed. And better than any upgrade is to backup and install fresh.

Comment: I have an HP Pavillion 15 laptop and I created a live USB and booted from that live USB by pressing F2, thinking that I'll upgrade it real quick using this method but there was no option for that.